# Time and second issue displaying 1:10 instead of 13:10

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jodatime

Hi i have the following class that format date:

```
public static final String DATE_DDMMMMYYHHMM_PATTERN = "dd MMMM yyyy, hh:mm";


      public static String formatDate(Date date , String pattern) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            String formatDate = "";
            if(date != null) {
                formatDate = sdf.format(date);
            }
            return formatDate;
        }
```

My unit test is show below:

```
@Test
public void testDateFormat(){

      DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2013, 11, 01, 13, 10, 00, 00); 
      Date date = dateTime.toDate(); 
      Assert.assertEquals("01 November 2013, 13:10", Main.formatDate(date,Main.DATE_DDMMMMYYHHMM_PATTERN)); 


}
```

Although that i have define time and second as 13:10 in my test  it is being displayed  as 01 November 2013, **01:10**.Any suggestion please what i can do in order that the time and second can be displayed as **13:10**?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your hour format from `hh` to `HH`

```
public static final String DATE_DDMMMMYYHHMM_PATTERN = "dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm";
```

According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
h - Hour in am/pm (1-12)
H - Hour in day (0-23)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static final String DATE_DDMMMMYYHHMM_PATTERN = "dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm";
```

You need to change hh to HH

The `HH` format represents the time in `HOUR(0-23)` whereas h h represents it in `1-12 am/pm` format

Also check the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for reference.